# Googlebot blocked by robots.txt

Tags: google, google-search-console, robots.txt

I have been checking the errors of my website in the google console , and I fount it face an error `Googlebot blocked by robots.txt` and it shows a link    https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js , that I did not used in my project. what is it ? my robots is this

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

How could I fix this error?

Comment: That robots.txt disallows everything on your site, is that what you want?

Comment: Doubleclick is an ad company owned by Google.  Do you you AdSense or other ads on your website?

Comment: You may not have used that script in your project, but AdSense scripts are sometimes pre-installed with and supported by various modules, plugins, third party services, etc, because this is a popular way to monetize your site. This is a script for instream ads (could be video ads related). You can manually remove it from your backend files if you want, but make sure you know what it'll affect. Google wants to crawl your JS files, but your robots file blocks this, so it's letting you know there are JS files it can't access. If you want your site indexed, remove the forward slash from line 2.

Comment: what thing will be disallowed ? No I do not have any advertisement on my pages . @StephenOstermiller

Comment: @HenryVisotski Thank you very much for valuable informations. You mean it should be like this :? `User-agent: *
Disallow: ` ( Disallow with just : ) ?

Comment: @HenryVisotski My website has been hacked recently , may that affect this?

Comment: Hi @nedaDerakhshesh - yes, that would be how it should be if you want your site indexed properly. That basically says, "all crawlers, disallow nothing." As for the hacked part, the script does seem legitimate (it's even secure) but if it wasn't there before the hacking, you may want to remove it anyway. If you were to restore your website to a cached point before it was hacked, would it still be there? That's the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are showing us the robots.txt file for the link that is blocked. robots.txt files vary per site. In this case https://static.doubleclick.net/robots.txt.

doubleclick are themselves saying, don't crawl our site. That is fine as Googlebot is not interested in ads. Quite a few third party tracking systems will do the same. It's nothing to worry about.

The robots.txt file for your own site will look different, and is probably fine.

Comment: Ok Tony so you mean there is no need to change anything?

Comment: Yep. Focus on something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your `robots.txt` file is wrong.
You are preventing the site from being indexed by `GoogleBot` or by any other crawler.
In case you want every bot to access your site, then it should be like this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Regarding the `https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js` error,
If the warning/error is about a site not in your control, then I think it is all right and will not affect anything.